# Ruby fixing multiple encoding documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding

I'm trying to retrieve a Web page, and apply a simple regular expression on it. 
Some Web pages contain non-UTF-8 characters, even though UTF-8 is claimed in Content-Type ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush)). In these cases I get:

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

I've tried to use the following methods for sanitizing bad characters, but none of them helped to solve the issue:

1. `content = Iconv.conv("UTF-8//IGNORE", "UTF-8", content)`
2. `content.encode!("UTF-8", :illegal => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")`

Here's the complete code:

```
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
@encoding = detect_encoding(response) # Detects encoding using Content-Type or meta charset HTML tag
if (@encoding)
  @content =response.body.force_encoding(@encoding)
  @content = Iconv.conv(@encoding + '//IGNORE', @encoding, @content);
else
  @content = response.body
end

@content.gsub!(/.../, "") # bang
```

Is there a way to deal with this issue? Basically, what I need is to set the base URL meta tag, and inject some Javascripts into the retrieved Web page.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you add a `u` to the end of the regexp. So it reads `/.../u, ""`?

Comment: @Gwilym, it didn't help.

Comment: Would you give another example URL?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have another URL right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem importing emails with different encodings, I ended with this:

```
def enforce_utf8(from = nil)
  begin
    self.is_utf8? ? self : Iconv.iconv('utf8', from, self).first
  rescue
    converter = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT') 
    converter.iconv(self).unpack('U*').select{ |cp| cp < 127 }.pack('U*')
  end
end
```

at first, it tries to convert from *some_format* to UTF-8, in case there isn't any encoding or Iconv fails for some reason, then apply a *strong* conversion (ignore errors, translit chars and strip non recognized chars).

let me know if it works for you ;)

A.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I get the error: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Comment: I've figured out how to fix your code: add `force_encoding('utf-8')` after `pack('U*')`, and I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: force_encoding works only on ruby 1.9, I wrote that code on 1.8 :P what do you think about?

Answer (score -1):

Use the  ASCII-8BIT encoding instead.